# Можно ли никак не обособлять "не успеешь глазом моргнуть"? "пока не надоест"?

Tags: пунктуация

> Даже в родном городе я люблю иногда пожить в какой-нибудь гостинице,
>   чтобы только ухватить дыхание чужих и таких далёких жизней, тех самых,
>   что сменяют друг друга не успеешь глазом моргнуть.

И буквально тот же случай и вопрос - "пока не надоест":

> Когда я стану ужасно богатой, то непременно найду правильную гостиницу
>   и стану жить в ней пока не надоест.

Comment: Я вот не уверен, что можно без "так, что".

Comment: Э, нет. Это в чистом виде авторская (персонажская) речь. Так могло быть произнесено? Значит, наша задача верно отобразить на письме.

Comment: Тогда согласен. Конечно могло. :)

Comment: А про запятые и их (не) необходимость рассказать?

Comment: Что рассказать? Что-то запутался))

Comment: Про необособление! довесочных! предложений!

Comment: Не знаю( Боюсь соврать. "Пока не надоест" мне кажется, что всё-таки надо обособить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во втором случае обособление обязательно: *Когда я стану ужасно богатой, то непременно найду правильную гостиницу и стану жить в ней, пока не надоест.*

Это явное постпозитивное придаточное предложение, нужна запятая.

А вот первый пример - вовсе не  **тот же случай**. Здесь более уместно тире:

*Даже в родном городе я люблю иногда пожить в какой-нибудь гостинице, чтобы только ухватить дыхание чужих и таких далёких жизней, тех самых, что сменяют друг друга - не успеешь глазом моргнуть*.

Формально это не придаточное предложение в СПП, а одно из простых в бессоюзном.

Обычно  это фразеологическое выражение с глаголом сов. в. употребляется как первая часть в составе сложного предложения, после которой обязательно следует союз *как* или *а.* Порядок слов-компонентов нефиксированный.

> Зачем ему громадный, грязный, тяжёлый мешок её проблем? Не успеет он и
>   глазом моргнуть, как ему придётся помогать ей тащить его, или он
>   ничего не понимает в жизни. Т. Устинова.
>
> - Не волнуйся! Ты не успеешь и глазом моргнуть, как уже всё кончится! (Реч.)
> - Не успели мы и глазом моргнуть, как уже приехали. (Реч.)
> - Я хотел сказать, что сегодня не обедал. <...> - Да мы сей момент, Ромик. Глазом не успеешь моргнуть, а у неё уже всё готово. Т.
>     Полякова, На дело со своим ментом.

Вот похожий случай без союзов у Марининой:

> Он не может уйти отсюда и добровольно дать себя арестовать, потому что
>   в этом случае <...> дело будет развалено - глазом моргнуть не успеешь.
>   А. Маринина, Шестёрки умирают первыми.

Мне кажется, здесь вполне уместно тире, в Вашем случае тоже тире более корректно. А совсем не обособлять отдельное предложение вряд ли возможно.

Comment: Люсенька, спасибо! Именно это ( и зап, и тире) у меня напрашивалось, но очень хотелось подтверждения.